# getting unable to get the value of the property lenght object is null or undefined in jquery.js file

Tags: jquery

Earlier I am using `jquery-ui-1.8.20.min` version file in my project,now I updated the jquery ui file reference with 1jquery-ui-1.11.4.min1 version.But now I am getting 
Microsoft `jscript runtime error:unable to get the value of the property length object is null or undefined in jquery.js file`

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: if the spelling error 'lenght' is in your code as it is in your question, then that likely to be the problem

Comment: spelling is not the issue here.its just typo.its length only.

Answer (score 0):

After adding the reference of jquery.1.11.4.custom js file issue is resolved.